# Subsequent MongoDB aggregate() calls operate on the result of the previous call!? (using NodeJS driver)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Consider the following code:

```
const db = mongodb.getDb();
            
// Results count
let count = (await db.collection('sec').aggregate(aggregateQuery)
    .group({ _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } })
    .project({ _id: 0, count: 1 })
    .toArray());
console.dir(count)

// test
let test = await db.collection('sec').aggregate(aggregateQuery).toArray();
console.dir(test)
```

The `aggregate(aggregateQuery)` filters the collection ad performs a lookup with another collection.
The first query counts all documents resulting from the aggregate, and it outputs `[ { count: 2086 } ]` as expected.
In my mind, `test` should contain a bunch of documents filtered from the collection (according to the aggregate operations), but it is just `[ { count: 2086 } ]`, as in the first query!

If in the second query instead of `aggregate(aggregateQuery)` I put `find()`, it outputs all the collection's documents, as expected, so I guess there is something I am missing in the `aggregate()` function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object passed as a parameter inside `aggregate` (`aggregateQuery` in this case) is modified by the following functions (`group` and `project`), so when it is used again in the second `aggregate` call, it is different and yields different results.

Comment: That's crazy! Oh, how I detest code that alters its inputs. Immutability ftw.

Comment: Me too, and I am not used to it at all, so it took me some time to figure it out!